# Lazy loading error when trying to use solr to index rich documents

Tags: apache, solr, apache-tika

I was trying to follow the tutorial on this page: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Sending_documents_to_Solr

But unfortunately, I keep getting a Lazy loading error whenever i execute the following command:

```
C:\xampp\solr\exampledocs>curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?litera
l.id=doc1&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true" -F "myfile=@tika.
html"
```

This is the error:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.29 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {fon
t-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:
22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525
D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;backgro
und-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;col
or:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:w
hite;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;backgroun
d:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR
{color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - lazy loading er
ror

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWra
ppedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:260)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handle
Request(RequestHandlers.java:242)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter
.java:365)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.extra
ction.ExtractingRequestHandler'
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:394)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:419)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:455)

        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWra
ppedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:251)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHa
ndler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:378)
        ... 23 more
</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>messag
e</b> <u>lazy loading error

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWra
ppedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:260)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handle
Request(RequestHandlers.java:242)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter
.java:365)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.extra
ction.ExtractingRequestHandler'
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:394)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:419)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:455)

        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWra
ppedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:251)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHa
ndler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:378)
        ... 23 more
</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error (lazy
loading error

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWra
ppedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:260)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handle
Request(RequestHandlers.java:242)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter
.java:365)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.extra
ction.ExtractingRequestHandler'
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:394)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:419)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:455)

        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWra
ppedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:251)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHa
ndler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:378)
        ... 23 more
) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="n
oshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.29</h3></body></html>
```

For what it's worth, I'm trying to use solr and tika on a windows xp machine.

Comment: Did you make sure you included the extra jars?